# Why this program with execl breaks if not run with sudo?

Tags: c, linux, macos, unix, exec

This is the **diner_info** program:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Diners: %s\n", argv[1]); 
    printf("Juice: %s\n", getenv("JUICE")); 
    return 0;
}
```

And it is compiled to a file called **diner_info**

And here is another program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *my_env[] = {"JUICE=peach and apple", NULL};
    execle("diner_info", "diner_info", "4", NULL, my_env);
}
```

When I run this program like this:

```
Korays-MBP:hello2 koraytugay$ sudo ./a.out 
Diners: 4
```

No problem...

But when I **do not include** **sudo** I am getting a segmentation fault. Why?

Operating system is OS X.

Comment: How do you compile the programs?

Comment: Perhaps, you compiled `diner_info` as root (with sudo) and normal user do not have permission to execute it? What does `ls -l diner_info` show? Can you execute `diner_info` directly without any problem?

Comment: @Cristik gcc filename.c -o filename

Comment: @BlueMoon -rwxr-xr-x  1 koraytugay  staff  8544 Apr 14 21:14 diner_info I do not know how to execute it from shell to be honest.

Comment: Do `gcc diner_info.c -o diner_info && ./diner_info` to compile and execute it.

Comment: If you use gcc filename.c -o filename, then how do you get to a.out? Shouldn't it be ./the_other_filename?

Comment: @Cristik I forgot the -o part for the second file.

Comment: Just tried compiling and running the programs on my mac, everything looks fine. Try deleting all binaries and recompile again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't, and you probably made some mistake with the first binary. I tested it on my MAC and on a Ubuntu 14.04 box, and both base runs fine:

```
brenohl@sid:/tmp$ ./a.out 
Diners: 4
Juice: peach and apple

brenohl@sid:/tmp$ cat diner.c 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *my_env[] = {"JUICE=peach and apple", NULL};
    execle("diner_info", "diner_info", "4", NULL, my_env);
}

brenohl@sid:/tmp$ cat diner_info.c 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Diners: %s\n", argv[1]); 
    printf("Juice: %s\n", getenv("JUICE")); 
    return 0;
}
```